# avoid AJAX-loaded CSS to modify the document

Tags: css, ajax

I'm loading an entire page with AJAX. That page contains some CSS, and when I load this page, the page loading it is modified by the loaded page's CSS.

For example, I have two pages:

Loading page (CSS is usually in an external file)

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1{color:#ff0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Title is red</h1>
<div>second page will be loaded here.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Loaded page

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1{color:#0000ff;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Blue title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

If I load the second page into the div of the first page via AJAX, the title of that page turns blue, and I want to avoid it.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.

```
$.GET('somewhere',function(data){
    $(data).find('div').appendTo($('#container'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I do so, styles from the loaded page won't append on it! For example, in this case, I would like my blue title to stay blue, and my red title to stay red.

Comment: @evuez Don't make it too complicated, `#container h1{color:#0000ff;}`.

Comment: my bad, that's working, and that's way simple to implement! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class or ID attribute to the header in the loaded page:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
h1.ext{color:#0000ff;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="ext">Blue title</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, if you don't have control of that one, to the loading page:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#mine {color:#ff0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="mine">Title is red</h1>
<div>second page will be loaded here.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't, the loaded documents come from google docs, and making some regex to add class/id to each style would take too much time for something like that.

Comment: Thanks, it works pretty well that way! The thing is, that's a really big work to do... But it seems to be the only working solution, so I'm going to do so!